# Quickly search for a specific window in vim based on filename

Tags: vim

Many times I end up opening a large number of files in vim using `split` and `vsplit`. In such a situation, is there some way by which I can search (by filename) for the window that has a specific file open?

I am looking for functionality similar to `tmux find window` where we can activate a window by searching for text in that window's scroll buffer. However, in case of of vim, I want to be able to set focus on a window by searching for the filename.

Comment: I don't think this is possible out-of-the-box. It would get fuzzy anyway since you can have multiple windows showing the same file -- and then what? (Also, be aware of the existence of [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 4):

first of all, opening multiple files in split makes file editing easier. However if you open "a large number of files" in split..... I don't know what reason makes you do it. If you want to batch process files, you can considering sed/awk/...

Anyway, you can execute this cmd line in your vim, you give the filename, and this cmd will bring you to the window containing the buf.

```
:call win_gotoid(bufwinid('YourFileName'))
```

Comment: Note: `win_gotoid` was introduced in Vim 7.4.1557. If you have an older version you can sort of get this behavior by using `:drop`. e.g. `:drop foo.txt`. The issue with using `:drop` is that if the file is not currently open then it will open the file in the current window. See `:h :drop` for more information.

Comment: I am running 7.4.1689 `$ vim --version | head -2
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 16 2016 10:50:38)
Included patches: 1-1689`. But it does not have `bufwinid` function. Nor does the `drop` command exist. I think I will have to try with a higher version of `vim`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `buffer` command and append the start of your file name - you'll then be able to tab complete the full name. To make tab completion a little more useful (IMO), you can add these settings to your `vimrc` file:

```
" first tab completed to the longest common match, or full match,
" second tab completed to show list of all matches,
" third tab starts to cycle through matches
set wildmode=longest,list,full
```

If you have 3 buffers open - `install.sh`, `readme.md`, `app.js` -

`:b in<TAB>` will complete the command to `:b install.sh` - pressing enter will open the buffer containing the `install.sh` file. If your search term has multiple matches, keep hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> to cycle through all the results.

For more info, checkout `:help buffer`

Comment: This opens the buffer *in the current window*. If I understood the OP correctly, he wants to *switch* to the window *already* displaying the buffer.

Comment: @DevSolar is right. I want to be able to switch to that window and not replace the current one.

Comment: @Amit - ah - I see. I suppose a compromise could be to open the desired buffer as a split (`:sb in<TAB>`)- but since you already said you have multiple splits open I don't think that would be much better. I'll leave this answer here because it might help someone else with a similar question.

Comment: @DevSolar - indeed you are correct. Thanks for the feedback!